# Sending HTTP content over multiple TCP connections

Tags: http, tcp

Is it possible for an HTTP content to be sent over multiple TCP connections?

If so, what fields indicate that this has occurred? I would assume `partial-content`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you ask the question the wrong way. A HTTP request consists of a single request header with optional body and in return of a **single response** header with a **single** optional body. Thus, by definition of the protocol there can be no such things as multiple HTTP response bodies to a single HTTP request.

But, a  **single content** can be spread over **multiple HTTP response bodies** by using **multiple HTTP request**. Single content is not the same though as a single HTTP body.

Answer (score -1):

The concept of [byte serving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_serving) is used to send only a portion of the message from the server to the client.

It is possible for multihomed HTTP client to request portions of the message over several TCP connections. This is accomplished through `GET` requests with the `Range` header specified.

The server will respond to each of these `GET` requests independently with responses that include the `Content-Range` header.

It is the responsibility of the HTTP client to reassemble the various message chunks.

Comment: You are answering a different question than you ask. You ask for sending a single **HTTP body** (which has [a clear definition](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-4.3)) over multiple TCP connection. You answer is instead if you can send a single **message** over multiple TCP connections. Yes, this can be done by using multiple HTTP requests and you get multiple HTTP bodies as response, not a single HTTP body.